# Command-line 'scm' loading all components from RTC

Tags: version-control, rtc

I'm trying to write a shell script to load all components from RTC.
When I succussfully logged on my RTC server and use `scm load`all components from a stream, and the error messages are:

```
Multiple components define share root "/.project":
  Component (1030) "Database"
  Component (1027) "FileSystem"
```

I don't quite understand what is that mean by `Multiple components define share root`
Can any one tell me how to fix this problem?